# How to create a new data frame according to the loop iteration?

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to create multiple data frames that are slices of an original data frame called `economy`, but I want to create the data frames to refer to the month and the year that they correspond to. This is the while loop I have so far:

```
month = 1
year = 2016

while year < 2018:
    while month < 13:
        start = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-1'
        if month == 2:
            end = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-29'
        elif month in (9,4,6,11):
            end = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-30'
        else:
            end = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-31'
        name = 'economy' + str(month) + '_' + str(year)
        name = economy[start:end]
        print(name)
        month += 1
    year += 1
```

but the loop is only adding every iteration to the data frame called name instead of creating a new one. I have tried to create a list of data frames for economy before the loop like below, but I don't know how to proceed to include it in the loop logic.

```
economy_list = []
for y in range(1,13):
    name = 'economy' + str(y)
    economy_list.append(name)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you share the `economy` DataFrame? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use a `dictionary` for you sliced `dataframe`s, and not a `list`, so that you can refer to each of them easily.

Second, as you know from the start how many "year"s and "month"es you will have, a `for` loop is the better option than a `while` loop.

So do:

```
economy_dict = {}
for year in range(2016, 2018):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        start = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-1'
        if month == 2:
            end = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-29'
        elif month in (9,4,6,11):
            end = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-30'
        else:
            end = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-31'
        name = 'economy' + str(month) + '_' + str(year)
        sliced = economy[start:end] #I copied from your code, but it doesn't seem right, and without sample of the data, I can't correct it if neccesary.
        print(name)
        economy_dict[name] = sliced
```

Comment: thank you, the solution worked very well! the sliced = economy[start:end] works because I set the date column as the index of the dataframe (: